# Getting better results from the "Ask" query than the main one

Tags: support, asking-questions

When I enter text in the "Ask" title box I get, in my opinion, better results than when I type the same thing in the main search box. Does this have something to do with how I enter the text or is the logic unalterably different? Are the two text box queries designed to expect different things and can I improve my results that way?

Example:

Text: "*Do we no longer need to ask for forgiveness?*"

I got the following results using the main search box:

> - A: What do the scriptures tell me to do after committing a sin?
> - A: Is repentance required for salvation?
> - Q: If the old priesthood is abolished, what is the point of having Catholic priests?
> - A: The Greatest Commandment - Loving God with all our 1) heart, 2) soul, and 3) strength

But I got the following results when I entered the text in the "Ask" title box:

> - If all our sins have been forgiven why do we need to keep asking to be forgiven?
> - Since God provided for the forgiveness of sins in the Old Testament, why do we need Jesus?
> - Why do we explicitly need to ask for help through prayer? [duplicate]
> - Why are there no longer large-scale miracles from God? [closed]
> - Forgive Others As We Have Been Forgiven?

The first couple from the Ask query seem to relate to my question perfectly whereas the results from the main box seem to be more loosely related. Certainly they are all related, I was just surprised how much *closer* the results from the Ask query were to my question than the main query.

Comment: See also: [Related questions in “Ask Question” page is better than search tool](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20432/1438), [A new search engine for Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100/1438), and [Add a “Magic 8-Ball” feature to the Ask a Question page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1696/1438).

Answer (score 5):

Surely this is a consequence of a restricted search field - the ask search is over [question titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27187/1438) (more likely to be directly relevant to you in this particular instance when you have a well defined question, but not necessarily in other cases) whereas general search includes Q & A bodies, tags, and titles.